# Chromium 81 won't display dotfiles anymore

Tags: ubuntu, chromium

Upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS brought with it a new version of Chromium and it also changed from a "traditional" package to a `snap` package (Snapplication?).

The about page shows `Version 81.0.4044.122 (Official Build) snap (64-bit)`

The upgrade broke my startpage, it is configured as `~/.dotfiles/startpage.html`, but the new chromium tells me

```
Access to the file was denied
The file at file:///home/<user>/.dotfiles/startpage.html is not readable. It may have been removed, moved, or file permissions may be preventing access.
ERR_ACCESS_DENIED
```

I know about [snap permissions](http://www.linuxandubuntu.com/home/snap-application-permissions), and I checked that chromium has access to my home folder.

The problem seems to be with the fact, that `.dotfiles` is hidden. When I move it directly to the home folder it works.

I don't really want to do that TBH, and there's no logical reason for me why it shouldn't work in a hidden folder. A file is a file is a file...., right?

For completeness' sake, my Firefox 75 displays the file without issue.

What am I missing?

Comment: Related upstream discussions: https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/dot-files/7062 | https://bugs.launchpad.net/snapd/+bug/1607067 I also have access blocked only to dotfiles, not other stuff in home.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a problem with snap, in the name of better security.

Quoting from the post
[Call for testing: chromium-browser deb to snap transition](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/call-for-testing-chromium-browser-deb-to-snap-transition/11179):

> paulw2u:
>
> As I can access these directories with Firefox and Chrome is this
>   something that needs to be fixed or is it a consequence of using a
>   snap?
>
> oSoMoN:
>
> This is indeed a feature of the snap confinement, it won’t let the
>   application see files on the host system (save for a few exceptions,
>   like $HOME). I’m aware this is mildly annoying when wanting to attach
>   e.g. log files to a bug report. Not much can be done about it, though.

The Ask Ubuntu post
[Why can't Chromium suddenly access any partition except for /home?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1184357/why-cant-chromium-suddenly-access-any-partition-except-for-home)
has two suggestions:

- Using the original non-native debian package from Google:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable
  ```
- Using the following command:

  ```
  snap connect chromium:removable-media
  ```

Comment: This seems to be only half the answer, chromium _can_ access my home folder, as I pointed out: I configured the startpage as `file:///home/<user>/startpage.html` and it works fine. Trouble starts when it is a hidden file. So neither `file:///home/<user>/.startpage.html` nor my original config works

Comment: This is probably another peculiarity of snap. Did the above advice help?

Comment: Sadly, no: The connect command did not change this behaviour, and it seems the packages have been removed with the transition from Ubuntu 19.10 to 20.04

Comment: Try Chrome [from Google](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-google-chrome-web-browser-on-debian-10/).

Comment: Yeah, that seems to work, since its not installed via snap. It doesn't seem to be an issue with chrome itself. Well, then I will have to live with it I guess

Comment: Since snap is still somewhat experimental, you could post this problem with dotfiles on their site or the Chromium site. Perhaps this was not done on purpose.

Comment: It seems to be on purpose, or at least known behaviour, according to this forum post:
https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/accessing-hidden-files/17180

Comment: Known, but seems that workarounds need to be found for each snap application, so unfortunately no general solution (for the moment).

Comment: unclouded dumbassing